I would like to build a hierarchy view that splits out data across multiple columns
I have 40k rows of data which is a combination of codes and parents codes. There are two columns, codes and parent code, so for example



Code
Parent code




A
2


B
1


1
3


2
B


3




What I want to extract is as follows:



Code
Parent Code
Third
Fourth tier




A
2
b
1



How can I do this in SQL?

Search for "adjacency list CTE recursion"
